# Suggestion/Edit for answers if user "Last seen more than X years ago"

Tags: support, editing, comments

I made a [suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/67045) (which was rejected) for this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124047/116593) but just because of that [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner) "Last seen more than 3 years ago" (at the time of posting this question)

I know that it is bad idea to edit someone's answer here, but what if user they aren't active anymore? In this situation, I believe that the comment is useless and may be deleted in the future by the system or a moderator.

Should I post my answer with the almost the same code just with fewer bytes?

Comment: In my opinion, you can just post your own answer in this case, or comment if you like.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should post your new answer and link to the original.

It perfectly fine, even when the OP is active, to post your golf as a separate answer. You don't need any further reason to do so.

A full answer can also give you the opportunity to explain your changes more completely, which can be nice.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!